# How to set Decorators for Input type file Elements?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have the following piece of code,
Under myClass , i have set decorators variable,

```
 public $testDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('Description', array('escape' => false, 'tag' => '', 'placement' => 'append')),
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'itemR')),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'itemL')
    ),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'itemcontent'))
);
```

Under CreateForm function,

....

```
    $cover_image = new Zend_Form_Element_File('cover_test', array(
      'label' => 'Cover Test:',
      'value'   => '',
      'class' => 'test',
      'tabindex' => '5',
      'required' => false,
      'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
          'decorators' => $this->testDecorators,
    ));
```

....

When i use this decorators, nothing is displaying in my form, if commented that `'decorators' => $this->testDecorators,` form is coming fine with default dd tag, Kindly help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file element must include the 'File' decorator, usually in place of the ViewHelper decorator. So try this instead:

```
public $testDecorators = array(
    'File',
    'Errors',
    array('Description', array('escape' => false, 'tag' => '', 'placement' => 'append')),
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'itemR')),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'itemL'),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'itemcontent'))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at what `$cover_image->getDecorators()` shows?

Also, is this one in the middle correct:

```
array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'itemR')),
```

should it not be:

```
array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'itemR')),
```

as the last one is?

Comment: His syntax is correct. You can only include one decorator with each name, the array syntax allows you to alias them.